# How to change the display name in the Google Play Store app?

Tags: google-play-store

In the Google Play Store app, the account name is shown inside the drawer menu.

[image]

How to change that name?

Answer (score 3):

There should be a pre-installed Android app in your phone called Play Games. Click that. You will see your username and your display pic. Click your username and then the top right edit icon of a pen. That way you can change your Google PlayStore username. 
Hope this helps :)

Comment: I tried it and it works! This should be the Accepted Answer.

Comment: This doesn't work for play store app reviews

Answer (score 2):

From Google help [Edit your Google Account information](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/27442?hl=en)

> You can edit information like your name, birthday, gender, and the email and phone number associated with your account. This basic information is used to help others get in touch with you more easily in products like Hangouts, Gmail, and Maps.
>
> - Sign in to My Account.
> - In the "Personal info & privacy" section, select Your personal info.
> - Choose the information you want to edit and follow the onscreen instructions.

Comment: But doesn't that change your username on your entire Google account? What if I wanted to change the display name without changing the name on the entire account?

Comment: I don't think it's possible

Comment: That is what I have concluded from subsequent web sleuthing as well.